# Regexp expresion for search ip address

Tags: python, regex

I need your help with set regexp expression for get ip address from dns names

I wrote a little script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

domains = [
    "us-west-2.elasticmapreduce.amazonaws.com",
    "ip-10-27-87-173",
    "ip-10-27-91-145.us-west-2.compute.internal",
    "ip-10-27-90-170.us-west-2.compute.internal.us-west-2.compute.internal",
    "ec2-54-82-117-121",
    "ec2-54-82-117-121.compute-1.amazonaws.com",
    "ec2-54-82-117-121.compute-1.amazonaws.com.us-west-2.compute.internal",
    "ip-10-27-102-175.us-west-2.compute.internal.us-west-2.compute.internal",
    "ip-10-27-180-213.us-west-2.compute.internal",
    "ip-10-27-107-136.us-west-2.compute.internal.us-west-2.compute.internal",
    "ip-10-27-209-104.us-east-1.compute.internal",
    "ip-10-27-209-104.us-east-1.compute.internal.us-east-1.compute.internal",
    "ip-10-27-209-104.us-east-1.compute.internal.ec2.internal",
    "ip-10-27-112-164.ec2.internal"
]

regexp1 = "(ip|ec2)-((?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?\-){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)))($|(?:ec2|[^.]+\.compute)\.internal\.$)?"


print("REGEXP: {0}".format(regexp1))
for domain in domains:
    result = re.match(regexp1, domain)
    if result:
        print("{0:>8} domain: {1:<90} matched with regexp, groups: {2:>30}".format("TRUE", domain, result.groups()))
    else:
        print("{0:>8} domain: {1:<90} not matched with regexp".format("FALSE", domain))
```

but result of this script:

```
   FALSE domain: ip-10-27-209-104.us-east-1.compute.internal                                                not matched with regexp
   FALSE domain: ip-10-27-209-104.us-east-1.compute.internal.us-east-1.compute.internal                     not matched with regexp
   FALSE domain: ip-10-27-209-104.us-east-1.compute.internal.ec2.internal                                   not matched with regexp
```

looks not good, I found that result is not so good for me:

problen in string:

```
ip-10-27-209-104.us-east-1.compute.internal
```

if I replaced 209 to value less then 200 and all worked well.
Something wrong with my regexp expression

Could you please help to find a reason of this behavior and optimize expression
Idea select ip address from dns name.

Thanks

Comment: `r"(ip|ec2)-((?:[0-9]+-)+[0-9]+)"` will extract all IP addresses why all this groups in your Regex?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `\-` is your problem. It's only present in the last option (when segment is between 0 and 199). The easiest solution is to add that to the first and second alternative as well:
`(ip|ec2)-((?:25[0-5]\-|2[0-4][0-9]\-|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?\-){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)))($|(?:ec2|[^.]+\.compute)\.internal\.$)?`

Answer (score 1):

Problem with your code is alternation, you have `-` included in last value only where as you need it after each value, you need to change your pattern in following way

```
(ip|ec2)-((?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)-){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))($|(?:ec2|[^.]+\.compute)\.internal\.$)?
```

[`regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/3Ugfzj/1)

And can be shortened a bit

```
(ip|ec2)-((?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d{1,2})-){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d{1,2}))($|(?:ec2|[^.]+\.compute)\.internal\.$)?
```

[`Regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/3Ugfzj/2/)

---

you can use regex visualizer tool to get a visual representation, [`Regeulex`](https://jex.im/regulex/)

[image]

Comment: thank you,
it works, but in that solution I lost possibility to extract an IP from group

Comment: @EduardAhmatgareev you can simply add ip in an captured group [`example`](https://regex101.com/r/3Ugfzj/3)

Comment: Unfortunately I found 1 more wrong case for me
Domains:
```
    "ip-10-27-212-164.ec2.internal",
    "ip-10-27-212-164.ec2.int",
    "ip-10-27-212-164.ec2",
    "ip-10-27-212-164.ec"
```

also returned groups and regexp was passed
but it's wrong domains